# How to work with sub table on Apache Poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to know how to work with snippet of `xls` file and operate with elements of snippet (Cells, Rows).

I nstead of working with full row.

Here is document looking:

[image]

I need to operate only with snippet, as:

[image]

Here is code snippet which works with `JXL`:

```
public class AncillariesWithPoi {

    private Workbook workbook;
    private EntryParser shortParser;
    private EntryParser longParser;
    private Sheet sheet;

    private Cell lowShortStart;
    private Cell lowShortEnd;
    private Cell highShortStart;
    private Cell highShortEnd;
    private Cell lowLongStart;
    private Cell lowLongEnd;
    private Cell highLongStart;
    private Cell highLongEnd;

    public void setDefault() {
        setRowKey(new CellReference("C30"), new CellReference("AR30"));
        setLowSeasonShort("D30", "U40");
        setHighSeasonShort("W30", "AN40");
        setLowSeasonLong("AR30", "BI42");
        setHighSeasonLong("BK30", "CC42");
    }

    public void setRowKey(CellReference firstRef, CellReference lastRef) {
        shortParser.rowKey = firstRef.getCol();
        longParser.rowKey = lastRef.getCol();
    }

    public void setLowSeasonShort(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.lowShortStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.lowShortEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    }

    public void setHighSeasonShort(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.highShortStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.highShortEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    // ommited rest of
```

How to work with sub table on apachte poi?

Generall I want to know how to implement next method with `apache poi` API:

```
    public void setLowSeasonShort(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.lowShortStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.lowShortEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    }
```

One posibility which I found at `poi` :

```
for (Row row : sheet1) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
            System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
            System.out.print(" - ");

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                // work with cell content
            }
        }
    }
```

It is iterating on cells from each row from sheet.

How to rewrite `setLowSeasonShort(String startCell, String endCell)` to working with `poi api`?

***Any suggestions?***

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to achieve. The code itself seems to already use POI. You have passed in the start and end cell references. Do you want to iterate over that range (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html)?

Comment: @GáborBakos yes exactly and work with this sub table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work for you:

```
CellRangeAddress range = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(startCell + ":" + endCell);
for (int row = range.getFirstRow(); row <= range.getLastRow(); ++row) {
    for (int col = range.getFirstColumn(); col <= range.getLastColumn(); ++col) {
         Cell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
         //do something with cell
    }
}
```

Naturally you can create a custom structure to visit only this part.